# How do I read a specific core's (performance counter) register?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, kernel

I can read/write a MSR register, but I don't know how to specify which core's MSR should be run.

For example, I want to record the L2 private cache miss of each core respectively, so I need to specify the core id for each core.

I know the smp_call_function() to call the code on all cores. If I add an insn that record the core ID this code is running and use the smp_call_function(), it should work. But if I only want to know core 1's L2 private cache miss, I will have to let all cores record the number, which is not neat to me.

Is there any better solution to this?

My codes for read/write operation MSR:

```
   mov $0x0001010E, %eax                # Write selector value to EAX
    xor %edx, %edx                       # Zero EDX
    mov $0x187, %ecx                     # Write logical register id to ECX (IA32_PERFEVTSEL1)
    wrmsr

  mov $0xc2, %ecx                      # Address of MSR IA32_PMC1
    rdmsr                                # Read value into EAX:EDX (EAX contains low-order bytes)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `smp_call_function_single` to run your code on a specific CPU.